# new csproj file / Compile Update

Tags: .net, msbuild, sdk, csproj

Moving a .NET WinForms Framework project to .NET 6/Visual Studio 2022, I was expecting the new .csproj file to be much smaller due to the implicit default compile items feature.

However, the old Compile Include lines seem to have been just replaced with hundreds of lines of Compile Update like this:-

```
<Compile Update="Reports\Accounts\IncomeReport.cs" />
```

Reading up on Compile Update in the SDK docs, it says it

> Enables you to modify metadata of an item

But none of these lines have any metadata so I commented out a bunch of these lines and everything compiled fine. I also opened one of the files in its designer and modified and saved it and no equivalent line was added back.

So is there any reason I shouldn't just delete all these lines to tidy up the .csproj file?

Comment: My guess would be backward compatibility. If it works for you, why don't you simply go ahead - after all your project is under version control, right?

Comment: You can safely delete such lines with empty `Update`. It also should improve build time a bit (a tiny little bit)